rEFInd "showtools" option not behaving properly
I've just installed Arch Linux alongside Windows, using the rEFInd boot manager to choose between them. Everything is working perfectly, except for the tools menu located below the main OS icons.
I would like the tools menu to only display the "shutdown" option, and to do that I added showtools shutdown to rEFInd's configuration file (/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf).
Doing that resulted in this. Not what I wanted.
After some more investigation, I've found that when showtools is specified with no options, this happens; it appears as if four extra tools are being appended after whatever I want.
When I commented out showtools completely, I got this. This output is the default which is described in refind.conf. It's the only time I've gotten what I've "asked for"
I've tried all sorts of combinations of showtools, hideui, and including an external theme's config. Everything is working as expected other than these four tools that just won't go away.
Thanks in advance for all the help!

This is a known issue and is currently tracked here.
Your best bet is to downgrade rEFInd to 0.14.1
